# Expandir y Contraer texto con css o jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tengo este ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".ver").on("click", function(){
      $(".p1").toggleClass("ocultar");
      $(".p2").slideToggle();
      if($(this).text() == "Ver más")
        $(this).text("Ver menos");
      else
        $(this).text("Ver más");
        
      return false;
   });
});
```

```css
p{
margin: 0;
}

.ocultar{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">Contenido oculto y mostrado a ...</p>
<p class="ocultar p2">Contenido oculto y mostrado a voluntad del usuario</p>
<a href="" class="ver">Ver más</a>
```

Lo que trato de hacer es mostrar un texto pero cortado y agregar un enlace que diga **ver más** y al hacer click sobre el se muestre el texto completo y cuando se vuelva a dar click sobre ese mismo enlace
que vuelva a mostrar el texto cortado.

El código que tengo no funciona bien porque primero oculta un párrafo y luego muestra el otro, y lo que necesito es que cuando se expanda el texto cortado se vea que muestra el texto restante y cuando se contraiga se vea que oculta el texto restante y deja el texto cortado como se mostraba originalmente, espero y me entienda.

Answer (score 0):

Añada 0 al $.toggle() esto hara que no se vea la transicion y consigue el efecto que deseas

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".ver").on("click", function(){
      $(".p1").toggleClass("ocultar");
      $(".p2").slideToggle(0);
      if($(this).text() == "Ver más")
        $(this).text("Ver menos");
      else
        $(this).text("Ver más");
        
      return false;
   });
});
```

```css
p{
margin: 0;
}

.ocultar{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">Contenido oculto y mostrado a ...</p>
<p class="ocultar p2">Contenido oculto y mostrado a voluntad del usuario</p>
<a href="" class="ver">Ver más</a>
```

Comment: Amigo funciona de maravilla, pero el problema es que el texto que voy a cortar lo voy a poner en un DataTable y ahí no funciona ya que el evento click no se agrega al enlace, como podría solucionar esto??